# reactjs useState update specific object inside array of objects

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a grocery list project.  With this project, when the user enters an item, I want to give the ability to edit said item.  I am storing everything inside an array of objects in my state.  The structure of my objects is:

```
{
 product: 'toast',
 category: 'bakery',
 quantity: 3,
 type: 'each
},
{
 product: 'apple',
 category: 'produce',
 quantity: 2,
 type: 'each'
},
{
 product: 'hamburger',
 category: 'meat',
 quantity: 1,
 type: 'Lb'
}
```

What I want to be able to do is have the user select one of those objects inside a card type function, then update it.  Currently, I can add items to the list, but I can not update them.

I have tried `setList(list[i].txt=v)` and `setList(list=>list[i].product=v)` plus other variations trying to target the specific object.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

The following is my main app.js code.  NOTE: `const Change()` is where I am trying to update the object.  The variables that I am passing in come from my item.js code

```
import React ,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import List from './components/list';
import Header from './components/header';

function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const Add = (p, c, q, t, crt) => {
    console.log({product: p, category: c, quantity: q, type: t, cart: crt})
    setList(list=>[...list,{product:p, category:c, quantity:q, type:t, cart: crt}])
  }
  const Change = (i, txt, v) => {
    //setList(list[i].txt=v)
    console.log('id: ' + i + ' topic: ' + txt + ' value: ' +v)
    setList(list=>list[i].product=v)
  }
  const Delete = () => {

  }
  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(list)}
      <h1>Grocery List App</h1>
      <Header add={Add}/>
      <List set={setList} lst={list} chg={Change} del={Delete} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This next code is my list.js file.  I am iterating over my list state and creating the individual 'cards' for each item.

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './item';

const List = (props) => {
    const productChange = (txt, v) => {
        console.log(props.lst[v].product)
    }
    const quantityChange = () => {
    }
    const cartChange  = () => {
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <p>To Find:</p>
            <ul>
                { props.lst.map((item, index) => 
                  item.cart === false ?
                    <Card 
                     key={item.index}
                     index={index}
                     value={index}
                     cart={item.cart}
                     item={item.product} 
                     units={item.quantity}
                     unitType={item.type} 
                     cartChange={cartChange}
                     itemChange={productChange}
                     quantityChange={quantityChange}
                     change={props.chg}
                     delete={props.del}/>
                  : null)
                }
            </ul>
            <p>Found</p>
            <ul>
                { props.lst.map((item, index) => 
                  item.cart === true ? 
                   <Card 
                    key={item.index}
                    index={index}
                    value={index}
                    cart={item.cart}
                    item={item.product} 
                    units={item.quantity}
                    unitType={item.unit} 
                    cartChange={cartChange}
                    itemChange={productChange}
                    quantityChange={quantityChange}
                    change={props.chg}
                    delete={props.del}/>
                   : null)
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
export default List;
```

This is the code for item.js. This is the final spot where I display the information from the list.  NOTE: `change()` from the first file is getting called here when I change the text of an input.

```
import React from 'react';
const Card=(props)=>{
    return (
        <li key={props.value}>
            <div>
                <input 
                  type="checkbox"
                  checked={props.cart}
                  onChange={(e)=> {props.cartChange(props.value)}} />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input 
                 id={'product '+ props.value}
                 className='update' 
                 type='text'
                 value={props.item} 
                 onChange={(e) => 
                       props.change(props.value,'product', e.target.value)
                 }
                 />
                <br/>
                <input 
                  id='quantityValue' 
                  className='update' 
                  type='number'
                  value={props.units} 
                // onChange={(e)=> 
                    props.quantityChange(e.target.value, props.value)}
                 />
                <span id='quantityType' className='update'>{props.unitType} 
                </span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button
                 id='save-button'
                 type='button' 
                 onClick={(e) => { props.change(
                                     props.item,
                                     props.units,
                                     props.unitType,
                                     props.value)
                                  }
                  }>&#10003; save</button>
                <button
                 id='delete-button'
                 type='button'
                 onClick={(e) => {props.delete(props.value)}}>&#10007; delete</button>
            </div>
        </li>
    )
}
export default Card;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to call `setList` with a list where you just amend that one object.
You can use `list.map()` for this. Ideally you want to add ID field to your objects.

But even without ID you can use index:

```
setList(list.map((product, index)=>{index == i ? v : product}))
```

or more verbose:

```
const Change = (i, txt, v) =>{
    const newList = list.map((product, index) => {
        return index == i ? v : product
    });
    setList(newList);
}
```

Comment: when I run your answer, I get the following error
`Line 13:40:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Comment: @PaulCarlson I updated my answer, please try more verbose version

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement `change` function. Is this right?

Try this one.

```js
  const Change = (i,txt,v) =>{
    setList(list.map((e, ei) => {
        if (ei === i) {
            e.product = v;
            return e;
        }
        return e;
    }));
  }
```

Comment: `e.product = v` is setting state directly, which is something that you should never do in React.